# Failed to install ruby 2.5.0 thru rbenv macOS High Sierra

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I am using macOS High Sierra and have been trying to install ruby 2.5.0 thru rbenv but keep getting error as following

```
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
compiling ./main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling miniinit.c
compiling dmyext.c
compiling miniprelude.c
translating probes probes.d
compiling bignum.c
compiling class.c
error: error reading '/dev/fd/9'
1 error generated.
clang: error: unable to remove file: Operation not permitted
dtrace: failed to compile script probes.d: Preprocessor failed to process input program
make: *** [probes.h] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....e
```

I tried `brew doctor` and `brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build` before install `rbenv install -v 2.5.0`

still getting the same error

Is anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: I have the same issue. I'll post here if I find a solution, but nothing yet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had similar problem while installing ruby with ruby-build (used by rbenv and others) and I've avoided it for now using following work-around.

This seems to be due to the `dtrace` being update with macOS 10.3.3.

First try [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/32910#issuecomment-69740819), `sudo chmod -s /usr/sbin/dtrace`

If that doesn't work then [disable dtrace](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1061#issuecomment-366127345) while installing ruby

`RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--disable-dtrace" rbenv install 2.5.0`

You can also `export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--disable-dtrace"` to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file.

The maintaner of [rbenv/ruby-build has notified](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1061#issuecomment-366671648) this to ruby core team and hopefully be fixed soon.

Answer (score 11):

I was getting crazy and nothing worked, but disabling the antivirus did the trick for me
(using Ruby 2.5.1 on High Sierra and Avira)

Comment: Wow.. just.. wow! Your comment has potentially saved me 3 days of debugging. Too bad I can only give you one upvote :) Too all fellow devs: try to disable avira realtime checking first.